# Calculating the reduced density matrix of two separate experiments

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, density-operator, trace

Consider setting up two experiments $\alpha $ and $\beta$.

In experimental setup $\alpha$ we can prepare $n$ possible pure states $\{| \psi_1 \rangle, | \psi_2 \rangle, ... | \psi_n \rangle\}$ with associated probabilities $\{p_1,p_2,...p_n\}$.

In experimental setup $\beta$ we prepare $m$ non-interacting systems. Each system  prepared in its corresponding lower energy states $\{| \phi_1 \rangle, | \phi_2 \rangle, ... | \phi_n \rangle\}$.

My question is how would one deduce the density matrix operators for the quantum states prepared in each experiment.
Is it simply a matter of noting that one can denote the density operator as  a sum of a set of projectors  as follows: $\rho = \sum_j p_j |j\rangle \langle j|.$

So then I may kind of assume that the density matrix operator for states prepared in $\alpha $ will be $\rho_{\alpha} = \sum_j p_i |\psi_i\rangle \langle \psi_i|.$

But I am unsure if this is correct I am also unsure how to construct the equivalent for experiment $\beta$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "we can prepare $m$ non-interacting systems prepared..." in the second set up. You know that all $m$ systems have been prepared, each in a pure state? or you know that one of them only has been prepared, but you don't know which?

Comment: It's also useful if you describe the possible ways of proceeding you thought about for the second question – even if vague – and why you excluded them. One of them could turn out to be right with some afterthought.

Comment: In experiment $\beta$ we generate m non-interacting quantum systems. Each system will be prepared in its lower energy state $\{| \phi_1 \rangle, | \phi_2 \rangle, ... | \phi_n \rangle\}$

Comment: You *can* generate, or you *do* generate? All of them at once?

Comment: Oh sorry that I was unclear. We do generate all at once.

Comment: Thank you for the more precise edit of your post. The density matrix for the first setup is correct. For the second setup, consider that you have a joint system with joint state $\lvert\phi_{i_1},\dotsc, \phi_{i_m}\rangle$, where $\phi_{i_k}$, with $i_k \in \{1,\dotsc,n\}$, is the state of the $k$th system. Then the density matrix is simply $\lvert\phi_{i_1},\dotsc, \phi_{i_m}\rangle\langle\phi_{i_1},\dotsc, \phi_{i_m}\rvert$ – that is, it's the density matrix that represents a pure state (of the joint system).

Comment: I think it'd be better if you explained why you're unsure, otherwise the bottom problem isn't solved.

Comment: No I think that's it. I think you explained it clearly enough for me, Its a lot more straightforward then I initially thought! Thanks!! I am aware that $\rho = |\Psi  \rangle \langle \Psi|$ but I did not realise that $|\Psi  \rangle = \lvert\phi_{i_1},\dotsc, \phi_{i_m}\rangle$

Comment: Great! By the way, note that "non-interacting" is a superfluous specification here. It's a property of the *dynamics* of a joint system, rather than its state. It means that its evolution operator has the form $U_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes U_m$, but it says nothing about its initial state.

Comment: I'll write this into an answer, otherwise moderators will (justly) complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some more thought you arrive at the answer for the second part of your question, since you have the correct understanding of the first part.

Setup $\alpha$: we know *one* system has been prepared in one of the $n$ possible pure states $\{\lvert\psi_1\rangle,\dotsc,\lvert\psi_n\rangle\}$. We don't know which, but we assign probabilities $p_1,\dotsc,p_n$ to the $n$ possibilities. Then the density matrix representing our knowledge of this setup is, as you correctly wrote, $\sum_i p_i \lvert\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i\rvert$.

Setup $\beta$: we know that $m$ systems have been prepared in $m$ pure states (possibly identical for some of them), each from among the set $\{\lvert\phi_1\rangle,\dotsc,\lvert\phi_n\rangle\}$. We also know the preparation state of each system, say $\lvert\phi_{i_k}\rangle$ for the $k$th system.

This means that their joint system has been prepared in the pure state $\lvert \phi_{i_1},\dotsc,\phi_{i_m}\rangle$, which is equivalent to the density matrix $\lvert \phi_{i_1},\dotsc,\phi_{i_m}\rangle\langle \phi_{i_1},\dotsc,\phi_{i_m}\rvert \equiv \lvert \phi_{i_1}\rangle\langle \phi_{i_1}\rvert \otimes \dotsb \otimes \lvert \phi_{i_m}\rangle\langle \phi_{i_m}\rvert$. (We're assuming that there are no bosonic or fermionic symmetrization complications.)

Saying that they're non-interacting is unimportant for the specification of the state (kinematics): that qualification refers to the dynamics of the joint system, meaning that it has the form $U_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes U_m$, where $U_k$ is the evolution operator acting on the $k$th system.

Just to add a reference, my favourite book about these topics: Bengtsson, Życzkowski: [*Geometry of Quantum States: An Introduction to Quantum Entanglement*](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511535048) (2nd ed., Cambridge 2017).

Comment: Quick question that is related to system $\beta$. If I consider a hermitian operator $\hat{O}$ that describes a physical observable associated with the kth system of $\beta$  would the expectation value of this operator simply be $Tr[\lvert \phi_{1}\rangle\langle \phi_{1}\rvert \otimes \dotsb \hat{O} \lvert  \phi_{k}\rangle\langle \phi_{k}\rvert \dotsb \otimes \lvert \phi_{m}\rangle\langle \phi_{m}\rvert]$

Comment: Yes – and you may notice that your expression can be simplified even further

Comment: To just the operator itself right?

Comment: right! The trace of a tensor product is the product of the traces.

Comment: Your help has been invaluable to my understanding!! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: You seem to have the correct notions already. Take a look at the book mentioned in the answer, it will give you a deep – and also visual – understanding.